# Can't verify access token signature from azure using nimbus

Tags: java, azure, jwt, access-token, nimbus-jose-jwt

following this [example](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/examples/validating-jwt-access-tokens) I wrote some code to validate an access token return by implicit flow from azure.

```
RemoteJWKSet remoteJWKSet = new RemoteJWKSet(new URL(jwksUri));
JWSKeySelector keySelector = new JWSVerificationKeySelector(JWSAlgorithm.RS256, remoteJWKSet);

ConfigurableJWTProcessor jwtProcessor = new DefaultJWTProcessor<>();

jwtProcessor.setJWTClaimsSetVerifier(new DefaultJWTClaimsVerifier(
      new JWTClaimsSet.Builder().issuer("https://sts.windows.net/3283e312-f73b-47d0-81c6-75e3ac726c21/").build(),
                new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("sub", "iat", "exp", "scp"))));

jwtProcessor.setJWSKeySelector(keySelector);

JWTClaimsSet claimsSet = jwtProcessor.process(accessToken.getValue(), null);
```

But the verification fails and I get:

```
com.nimbusds.jose.proc.BadJWSException: Signed JWT rejected: Invalid signature
    at com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor.process(DefaultJWTProcessor.java:378)
    at com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor.process(DefaultJWTProcessor.java:303)
    at com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor.process(DefaultJWTProcessor.java:294)
```

I think I don't need `DefaultJWTClaimsVerifier` part, but removing it doesn't change anything. I iust keept it to stick with the example.

Do you know why this happends?

Thanks for your help.

PS: Can't verify with jwt.io. I pasted access_token and the first entry from "keys" section from jwk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `expose an API scope` in Azure, and get the client to use that. Also ensure that there is no `nonce` field in the JWT header of the access token. My [blog post](https://authguidance.com/2017/12/01/azure-ad-spa-code-sample/) has further info.

**AZURE AD BEHAVIOR**

The above behavior is quite specific to Microsoft, and is required when using Azure AD as a provider:

- Tokens with a nonce field in the JWT header are designed only for MS APIs, eg Graph, and use an in-house validation mechanism. The intent is for these to always fail validation in custom APIs.
- Tokens for your own custom APIs must be retrieved via clients that request custom scopes. Note that the OAuth client configured in Azure AD can be a logical entry, rather than needing to maintain one for each individual API.

I believe the MS behavior is based on [OAuth resource indicators](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8707), though my personal preference is to use more mainstream techniques of [scopes](https://curity.io/resources/learn/scope-best-practices/), [claims](https://curity.io/resources/learn/claims-best-practices/) and audience checks when receiving access tokens in APIs.

Comment: Changing the issuer didn't help. I looked up your blog post but I don't understand why I can't verify a token with a nonce. What is the point of a nonce if I can't verify it?

Comment: I don't know why but the scope fixed my problem. My issuer was correct, if you update your answer I will accept it. Bonus points if you can explain why I need to add the scope.

Comment: It is MS specific behavior, and a little unusual - I have always found it a little unintuitive though it is related to standards. You have to accept it when using Azure AD. I added some more background to my answer.